# Connecting SIM900A GSM/GPRS module Arduino Mega

Tags: gsm

I have bought the following SIM900A GSM/GPRS module. I need to connect it to an Arduino Mega. Can anyone answer me which pin I need to connect to the Arduino?

[image]

Comment: GSM modules works on serial protocol. You will have to connect Rx Tx of GSM to Tx Rx of arduino but before that try googling for `Interfacing GSM with arduino`. Also this question should be migrated to Arduino SE

Comment: hai, Thanks for your reply. actually i have tired in searching for the exact board data sheet. there is additional TTL RX,TX and ground can be seen next to the serial port. and there are six pins behind the serial port one set covered by green jack and other two by blue. most of the googling showed we have to remove those jacket to use this module with arduino. but those modules don't have the TTL pins which i have told earlier.

Answer (score 0):

From your pic, it looks like the upper left corner has a jumper with TTL level TX, RX, GND.

Comment: hai, thanks. i am also thinking your way. but i am not sure whether it is right or wrong. but if i go for this way do i need to do any changes on the pins behind the serial port which are covered by green and blue jacks. which i mean do i need to remove the jacks..or else any kind of changes...??